# Hibernate many-to-many mapping and query to go with it

Tags: mysql, hibernate, database-design, hibernate-mapping

I'm having some trouble getting the hang of HQL.  I have an application where I have a bunch of competitors in one table.  Then I have competitions, where I match up the competitors.  Each competition may have any number of competitors.  And each competitor may be in multiple competitions.  (In fact, I'm setting up a "round robin" competition, so all competitors will be in lots of competitions, to ensure they play every other competitor.)

Rather than creating the join table myself, I am trying to use Hibernate's XML to create the join table.  Ultimately, I THOUGHT I should be able to write something like the following HQL query:

```
select count(*)  from Competition c where c.competitor.id = :competitorId
```

Simple query that's actually part of a bigger query.  My intent is to count the number of competitions where a given competitor is participating.  The problem I'm encountering though are errors like:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: competitor of: com.sodapopsoftware.imagewar.model.db.Competition [ select count(*)  from com.sodapopsoftware.imagewar.model.db.Competition c where c.competitor.id = :competitorId ]
```

Here are my mappings for competition and competitor.

**COMPETITION**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.sodapopsoftware.imagewar.model.db.Competition" table="competition">

    <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
    <meta attribute="extra-import">java.util.Set</meta>
    <meta attribute="extra-import">java.util.TreeSet</meta>

    <id name="competitionId" column="competition_id" type="int">
        <meta attribute="scope-set">protected</meta>
        <meta attribute="field-description">Primary Key</meta>
        <meta attribute="use-in-equals">true</meta>
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="league" column="league_id" unique="false" not-null="true"
        class="com.sodapopsoftware.imagewar.model.db.League"
    />
    <property name="dateAdded" column="date_added" type="date" not-null="true">
        <meta attribute="field-description">When the league was created</meta>
    </property>
    <set name="competitors" table="competition_competitors" sort="com.sodapopsoftware.imagewar.model.util.CompetitorIdComparator">
        <meta attribute="property-type"><![CDATA[Set< Competitor >]]></meta>
        <meta attribute="default-value"><![CDATA[new TreeSet< Competitor >()]]></meta>
        <key column="competition_id"/>
        <many-to-many column="competitor_id"
            unique="false"
            class="com.sodapopsoftware.imagewar.model.db.Competitor"/>
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**COMPETITOR**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.sodapopsoftware.imagewar.model.db.Competitor" table="competitor">

    <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
    <meta attribute="extra-import">java.lang.Comparable</meta>
    <meta attribute="implements">Comparable<![CDATA[<]]> Competitor <![CDATA[>]]></meta>
    <meta attribute="class-code">    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;</meta>
    <meta attribute="class-code">
public int compareTo( Competitor that ) {
    if ( that != null ) {
        return this.getCompetitorId() - that.getCompetitorId();
    }
    return 1;
}
    </meta>
    <id name="competitorId" column="competitor_id" type="int">
        <meta attribute="scope-set">protected</meta>
        <meta attribute="use-in-equals">true</meta>
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="league" column="league_id" unique="false" not-null="true"
        class="com.sodapopsoftware.imagewar.model.db.League"
    />
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string" not-null="true">
        <meta attribute="field-description">Gives this competitor a name</meta>
    </property>
    <property name="nameNormalized" column="name_normalized" unique="true" type="string" not-null="true">
        <meta attribute="field-description">Same as name, but lower case for searching</meta>
    </property>
    <property name="description" column="description" type="string">
        <meta attribute="field-description">Describes this competitor</meta>
    </property>
    <property name="linkImageThumbnail" column="link_image_thumbnail" type="string" not-null="true">
        <meta attribute="field-description">Link to the thumbnail image for this competitor</meta>
    </property>
    <property name="linkImageFullSized" column="link_image_full_sized" type="string" not-null="true">
        <meta attribute="field-description">Link to the full-sized image for this competitor</meta>
    </property>
    <property name="dateAdded" column="date_added" type="date" not-null="true">
        <meta attribute="field-description">When the competitor was created</meta>
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your query uses the syntax for references (ManyToOne) but one/many-to-many need explicit join to have an alias for the elements

```
select count(*)  from Competition c join c.competitors co where co.id = :competitorId
```

Comment: Do you gods find it tiresome when people are constantly bowing down and thanking you?